# Converting older, existing dng through adobe dng converter?

Tags: dng

All of my photos (cr2 raw) are converted to dng during import into Lightroom 5.71.

I was just wondering if there would be any benefit to running my existing dng's through the free Adobe dng converter. I understand that the most recent ACR is 9.8. Would running my dng's through Adobe dng converter somehow update my dng's with the updates from ACR 9.8?

If I am not understanding this correctly, I apologize. But perhaps someone could shed light on my question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just another reason why I would never convert my .cr2 files to .dng. Or if I did I would also keep copies of the original .cr2 files.

Comment: What are you expecting to have happen to your files? The .dng space hasn't changed, and new versions of ACR don't alter your RAW files. I'm not sure what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original data in the CR2s should be preserved in the automatically created DNGs LightRoom made for you.

A DNG can be thought of a a generic file format wrapping multiple types of RAW files from different makers.  ACR version does not affect that format.

No additional data or detail will turn up doing that.

The new version of ACR may have slightly different processing algorithms that may generate different processed images than your previous versions, but ACR itself has no effect on the actual raw data in the DNGs.  This means you might see (slight) changes in the final image file ( JPEG usually ) generated by LightRoom using the new version of ACR, but these would probably be minute.

There's no reason to convert to DNG using a different app ( than LightRoom ) or updating your DNGs just because ACR changes unless some new version of ACR in the future requires a new format of DNG and rejects your existing DNGs ( which it should not ).